# Tradução de fechamento

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Já alguém reparou que os fechamentos estão em inglês ou é só a mim?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fica também a lembrança de traduzir o

> add comment

Já agora a *tag* `bug` não deveria ser "erro" ou qualquer coisa assim?

Comment: Acho que `bug` é claro e generico o suficiente, embora não discordo que poderia ser outra coisa, não vejo a necessidade de troca.

Comment: Isso foi "destraduzido" recentemente, não sei bem o pq

Comment: Sim eu percebi @Math

Comment: A parte do "add a comment" já tinha sido reportada aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1752/adicionar-coment%C3%A1rio-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-traduzido